# Marklogic Datahub: Generation of Triples

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am using Data Hub Quick Start V5.4.0 and Marklogic Version 10.0-6.0

I have a few tdex files in data-hub-FINAL-SCHEMAS.

In the Marklogic console, When I select data-hub-FINAL and execute the SPARQL query:

```
SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p ?o}
```

I am able to get the triples in the output.

When I manually update on of the tdex file (In the Marklogic Console) and run the SPARQL query again, I am not able to see the modification in the triples.

Want to know how to edit the tdex file so that I can get the updated triples when I run the SPARQL Query.

Comment: Are you applying your TDE's on a large dataset? It may still be re-indexing, which needs to finish for changes to show up.

Comment: Please elaborate on ** how ** you are updating the template via query console..  as an example: you could be updating by xdmp functions instead of tde functions. The results are not the same (one adds critical colections, the other does  not)  step by step example will fill in the blanks ans allow people to assist more.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to security. Are you sure that the user has the correct read permissions on the TDE template once you re-insert it into the database manually from QueryConsole?

I would compare the TDE template permissions before and after the modofication and see if perhaps you dropped some permissions on the replaced TDE without realizing it.

Comment: The user is an Admin here and I have compared the permissions on the TDE file before and after the update to it. The permissions are not changed.

Below are the permissions:

data-hub-entity-model-writer => Update
data-hub-common => Read
tde-admin => Read, Update
tde-view => Read

Comment: See my coment under the main item requesting elaboration